# Save toggle state with jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I would like to save the state toggled depending what user has selected.

My code looks below:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  stuff here
</div>

<script>
   $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
   });
</script>
```

If I had class toggled set to id wrapper then the div is toggled by default.

How can I solve this with a cookie? So It remebers what user has clicked, so it sets the div eighter to toggled or not toggled on page reload.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure cookies will be the best option. Maybe [localStorate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a more viable and easier option.

You can use it like this:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var element = $("#wrapper");
   element.toggleClass("toggled");
   if (element.hasClass("toggled")) {
     localStorage.setItem('toggled', 'true');
   } else {
     localStorage.setItem('toggled', 'false');
   }

 });

 // On load
 var element = $("#wrapper");
 var toggled = localStorage.getItem('toggled');;
 element.toggleClass("toggled");

 if (toggled == "true")
   element.addClass("toggled");
 else
   element.removeClass("toggled");
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8tpxx71z/

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Hi, what a great example. I have added some of my code as with your fiddle and the only problem is that the animation is runnig everytime on page refresh (untoggled).. is there any way to disable this so that anymation is only running on click. 

Fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/r3qpuuem/